# what is the easiest way to read and process serial data for windows 32-bit systems?

Tags: c, winapi, io, serial-port

hello and good day to you guys. I am running Windows XP which I am given to understand is a 32 bit windows system.

I have a microcontroller that continuously sends data serially through a COM port. I want to process data in a C program. The options I'm looking at so far are:

1. get serial data via python and pass to C
2. read data serially and use in C

The first option seems too hard for me. I was trying to use swig and am stuck. 
any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find it much easier just to receive the data straight via C, if you're going to process it there in the end anyway. [Here's a quick overview](http://www.robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf) of how to set things up. Essentially you call [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on, eg, `"COM1"`, then use [`GetCommState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`SetCommState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363436%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the resulting handle to configure the port. If you need to do GUI interaction as well, have the reading code run on a different thread, and communicate the data it reads back to the GUI thread by posting custom (`WM_USER`, etc) messages to one of your windows.

Comment: this. There are enough serial port examples on the net, and the code is pretty simple.